# International phone number format ios

Tags: ios, swift

In my country(Kazakhstan) phone number `+7 (123) 456 7890` is equal to `8 (123) 456 7890`.
So one saves numbers with `+7`, some with `8`. I need to compare and verify these two numbers. It is easy, but I wonder if there are countries with rules like this and how to check them?

P.S. It is for an ios app in swift.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit ?

Comment: how can install it manually? no cocoapods

Comment: I recommend you to use Carthage - it's very easy to use. If you want to add it manually you have to download and just add all source files to you project.

Comment: i tried to just add all source files to the project, doesn't work

Comment: thanks, @TomaszPikć!